# Rejected to connect from lambda to cognito due to not authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

If CognitoIdentityProvider::Client doesn't provide access_key_id and secret_access_key, it will retrieve from the ENV by default.

The strange thing is it works at a totally new lambda but not in another.

```
client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
client.admin_get_user({
  user_pool_id: Jets.application.config.cognito[:user_pool_id],
  username: 'username'
})
```

I would get this error message but had no idea where can I set the policy for cognito.

```
  "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::123123123123:assumed-role/firstage-api-stag-IamRole-1DYOOEVSCURMY/xxxxxx-api-stag-mes_controller-show is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminGetUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-northeast-2:319924209672:userpool/ap-northeast-2_0cSCFMK4r",
  "errorType": "Function<Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::AccessDeniedException>",
```

I would like to use the default key_id and access_key in the lambda ENV rather than IAM user.

What should I do???

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for Lambda functions is to ensure your IAM role associated with the Lambda function has the policy to let it invoke the specific AWS Service. Do not hard code creds in Lambda functions.

For some services, you need to write a custom policy. For example, for Pinpoint voice, you need to write a custom policy using JSON so the Lambda function can invoke that service.

For **CognitoIdentityProvider**, try using this policy for your IAM role:

[image]

When in doubt which services your IAM role can invoke - check the **Access Advisor** tab:

[image]

I just tested this use case and built a Lambda function that creates a **CognitoIdentityProviderClient** object and gets users in a specific user pool. I implemented this using the **Lambda Java runtime API**, but it does not matter what supported Lambda programming language you use. You still need to configure your IAM role in the same way.

This code works perfectly. Here is the Handler class:

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String> {

        @Override
        public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context) {

            LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
            String pool = event.get("Pool");
            logger.log("pool: " + pool);

            CognitoInfo cog = new CognitoInfo();
            String xml = cog.getUsers(pool);
            logger.log("XML: " + xml);
            return xml;
        }
    }
```

Here is a method named **getUsers** located in the **CognitoInfo** class that invokes the AWS Service:

```
public String getUsers( String userPoolId) {

        CognitoIdentityProviderClient cognitoclient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        try {

            ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList();
            // List all users
            ListUsersRequest usersRequest = ListUsersRequest.builder()
                    .userPoolId(userPoolId)
                    .build();

            ListUsersResponse response = cognitoclient.listUsers(usersRequest);
            for(UserType user : response.users()) {

                userList.add(user.username());
            }

            return convertToString(toXml(userList));
        } catch (CognitoIdentityProviderException e){
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The Lambda function is configured to use an IAM role named **lambda-support2**  that has the **AmazonCognitoPowerUser** policy.

[image]

This Lambda function successfully retrieves the users in a specific user pool:

[image]

Make sure that all your Lambda functions have the proper IAM role configured.